# "Why was my Identify question closed"?

Tags: discussion, identify

Today, I went through (and still am) about ~70 questions all tagged either [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) or [identify-this-tv-show](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-tv-show).

I closed any question that

- Had no accepted answer
- Has had no update in the past Month (registered users) / 2 weeks (unregistered users)

However, I am **not** deleting these questions.  This is a way for me to kind of mass ***poke*** these askers with a message of "Do you have anything else to say about your question?"

As always, if you would like your question reopened, apply an edit with any updates you may have and flag it for mod attention.  I would be more than happy to re-open them for you.

If you have found what you are looking for **Share**.  Answer your own question with the answer and accept it. **It is perfectly acceptable to do so**

Comment: Shouldn't the ? go inside the quotes?

Answer (score 6):

Just an fyi for future readers, identification questions are a sort of middle of the road type of question, and it tends to polarize people on their opinion.  There are a lto of people **for** keeping identification questions, and a lot of people **against** keeping identification questions.

We're taking a somewhat middle of the road approach for these questions.  We allow them, but they have to be of a decent quality.  Also, if an identification question isn't answered per the stats Tyler mentioned above, then it's likely that the question is either too localized, or just doesn't have enough information for someone to figure it out.

So this is not a crusade against users that prefer identificaiton questions, or a crusade against identification questions.  But rather, we're trying to keep the quality of the movies site to the point where our users are engaged in the content and want to keep coming back.

Comment: Are we going to get a final decision on this "polarizing" issue? Didn't we take the pulse of the matter? Can we get off the "Dump the bastards" pulpit even if the decision went against TylerShads?

Comment: @wbogacz identification has been thoroughly discussed, but here's what we're considering the final say in the matter http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/443/discussion-on-identification-questions

Comment: @wbogacz as for those that are complaining about identification questions, i don't know.  i don't like beating a topic to death.  we've already had two polls at least for identification questions, and the general consensus is usually to keep them.  but there are a few (ahem, tylershads) that are against keeping them.  However, tyler has not shown any malice towards this type of question (ie closing them for no reason, etc.), so to be honest just ignore it.  if you do see someone doing something out of spite though, please make sure to flag it to let us know.

Comment: I'm pretty knowledgeable about the identification question policy. But this is new, the drive to close them. If this is the method we are employing on "legitimate" questions why are we not closing older non-identifaction questions that are as "legitimate" and meet the same criteria? These questions ARE being classified differently and treated especially differently. These questions have become the "Hanging Chads" of M&TV, legitimate enough, until it's convenient to believe they are not. I think this whole cleansing is spiteful, and this serves as my notice to let you know so.

Comment: @wbogacz The fact of the matter is identify are guessing games, based on vague details.  If I asked you to guess what I'm thinking, you'd likely respond with "I'm not a mind-reader" which is why these things hinder a Q&A site where an answer is expected.  The community, however, wants them, but most are utter crap produced by people who will never come back, more so than any other question type.  So we decided, in open chat and [meta discussions](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/380/should-we-close-older-identify-questions), to close those too old that haven't had

Comment: *any* attention, views, answers, etc. In the period of times above.  Notice they aren't being *deleted* which removes them from public view completely, they are still indexed by google, still allowed to be edited, commented on, etc.  If someone has an answer or an update, a simple click gets it open for answering again.

Comment: @wbogacz There is an astronomical difference between a constructive question that hasn't been answered because someone hasn't bothered to answer it or doesn't know the answer (Who, what, where, why when) and a "I remember X & Y, what is this?"  If you can only see the flag history and the mod history, you'll see that we are presented with crap that gets closed and deleted. Maybe not as frequently as parent sites like SO/SF/SU/Gaming, but they do exist and users don't see them because we squash them as they come.