# What about "What do you recommend me if i like ___ ?" questions

Tags: discussion

I discovered movies.stackexchange.com and was willing to contribute and make it grow.
BUT, the questions I was first thinking of was all of the kind:

- Which movies with an impredictable end do you recommend me ?
- I loved "Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas" what could I watch now ?
- Which "drama"-kind movies would I like if I loved xxx and yyy ?

I guess this is not the aim of the Q&A site. How am I supposed to deal with requests for recommendations ? Maybe SE is not the right place for that.

Comment: Also, i try to be in chat as often as possible.  Always feel free to hop in chat and ask for help on framing a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommendations are considered off-topic, and for a good reason.  The first being that there is no real clear answer to recommendation questions.  The second is that recommendation questions very rarely help out other users besides the initial asker.  These types of questions are easy to ask, but bring very little quality content to the site.  Also, questions like this tend to irritate users that are looking for a more analytical and informative experience, and those are the ones that are needed on sites.

We tryed using recommendations on the literature site, but that failed pretty hard.  Only only thing I can think of to suggest is to try hopping in chat and asking us for recommendations there.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What I understand is that the movies Q&A is more for debates or for specific questions than a place to aggregate advices.

Comment: @kheraud actually we are not about debates.  Having a debate would include multiple parties going back and forth on a topic, which we don't do.  You can get multiple viewpoints on a question though, such as on some of our Dark Knight Rises questions.

Comment: The claim that *recommendation questions very rarely help out other users besides the initial asker* is very common, but I seriously don't buy it.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that this SE is not the place for recommendations and here is why.

- They are subjective at best.  Everyone has an opinion so which is the correct answer?
- They are not constructive and are purely opinion based questions.   Just because you like movie XX doesn't mean someone else likes it.

It's not a secret that personally [I have a problem with identification questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/575/why-was-my-identify-question-closed).  The idea of allowing recommendations would just be a terrible idea for the quality of the site as well as those of us looking for a place that is more than just a recommendation area.

The best place for movie recommendations would be the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room).